# PLSQL read value from XML (Again)?

Tags: xml, oracle, plsql

I posted a while ago a [question about how to read values from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016399/plsql-read-value-from-xml), and there was a perfect answer, it was so neat and so simple yet I can not understand it and apply it on some other XML!!!

can some one help me with this one? I need to read the "id" or the "ChangeKey"

```
<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Header>
 <t:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="8" MinorVersion="2" MajorBuildNumber="217" MinorBuildNumber="0"/>
 </soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<m:CreateItemResponse>
<m:ResponseMessages>
<m:CreateItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Success">
 <m:ResponseCode>NoError</m:ResponseCode>
<m:Items>
<t:CalendarItem>
 <t:ItemId Id="erwrweff3424dfw23r2fwfwsfwsfg34fwdf2" ChangeKey="sdfwwerw4224rw"/>
 </t:CalendarItem>
 </m:Items>
 </m:CreateItemResponseMessage>
 </m:ResponseMessages>
 </m:CreateItemResponse>
 </soap:Body>
 </soap:Envelope>
```

I really don't feel good because I'm not able to understanding it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the same thing as in the [answer you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016399/plsql-read-value-from-xml), but change the XPath expression (second argument to XMLTYPE) from

```
'//SOAProxyResult'
```

to e.g.

```
'//t:ItemId/@Id'
```

or

```
'//t:ItemId/@ChangeKey'
```

The third argument will need to declare the t namespace prefix:

```
'xmlns:t="foobarbaz"'
```

and of course your input XML will need to declare that namespace prefix too.

Comment: Thanks allot, but that's how I get the XML from the server! without namespace!

Comment: and I have to add  xmlns:t="foobarbaz" xmlns:soap="foobarbaz" xmlns:m="foobarbaz" so it will work, hmmmmmmmm

Comment: No worries I solved it, I created a function that delete :SOAP, :t, :m from the xml code and then run it with out namespaces, worked perfectly, thanks allot for the help

Comment: Bleah, you're getting not-namespace-wellformed XML from the server? I would tell whoever's responsible for that service that it's outputting garbage.